STS 4.24.0: JMX actuator beans show in jconsole but not in STS
With 4.24.0: I can't access the actuator jmx beans within STS where the error message is " application must be running with JMX and actuator endpoint enabled"

by JMX(jconsole): I can scrape MBeans/org.springframework.boot/Endpoint/Beans/operations/beans and that gives output showing all the beans.
by JMX(inside STS): General, Request Mappings, Env are all working; Beans is the only one not working

So - any suggestions why scraping JMX/MBeans...beans works in jconsole but not within STS Boot Dashboard?
All the spring.* management.* properties are correct otherwise it wouldn't scrape in jconsole.
STS 4.24.0 on Fedora 40

works with 4.23.1
just in case it was my application I created a brand new Spring starter project in the workspace with Web and actuator and I can reproduce the issue with a practically blank project.
also reproduces with 4.25 nightly build


This is https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1350 and already fixed for the 4.26.0 release, scheduled for late October.
If you want to get the fix earlier, feel free to grab a snapshot build from https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html
